# gmailr package Query Gmail Stats with R

Tags: r, gmailr

I am trying to pull stats from the gmail API using R.  I am using gmailr package. I am able to send an email from R but that's about where it ends.  I was using these links to try to figure this out but it does not seem to be working: https://github.com/jennybc/send-email-with-r/#prep-work-related-to-gmail-and-the-gmailr-package and https://github.com/alkashef/gmailstats

All I really want to see is how many daily emails are received, and if possible, break it down by the hour.

Any assistance in this would be wonderful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
library(gmailr)
clientid <- "...."
key <- "...."
token <- gmail_auth("read_only", clientid, key)
msgs <- messages(search = "before:2018-01-01 after:2016-01-01", include_spam_trash = FALSE)
msgs_meta <- lapply(id(msgs), message, format = "metadata")
dates <- lubridate::dmy_hms(sapply(msgs_meta, date))
addmargins(table(as.Date(dates), factor(format(dates, "%H"), levels = 0:23)))
#             0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 Sum
# 2016-11-10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
# 2016-11-11  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
# ...
# 2017-12-27  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
# Sum         0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 15  5  1  0  0  4  3  2  2  0  1 22 19  3  77
```

The explanations are pretty much found in the links that you provided yourself.

Comment: OK, what would the clientid and key be?  Like what is the format?  I think this is where it is getting hung up but not 100% sure.

Comment: @chris Read & follow https://github.com/jennybc/send-email-with-r/#prep-work-related-to-gmail-and-the-gmailr-package, then copy, paste and trim both. Otherwise add to your post what you did, maybe with screenshots where you obfuscate your credentials of course.